# Debian df - What are my partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, debian, df

I have a debian server hosted by Kimsufi. It has 2TB of HDD storage. When I run `df -h` on my server I get this output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G  1.3G   17G   8% /
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G   18M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3       1.8T   75M  1.7T   1% /home
```

I store most of my data in `/var/www/html` for apache etc but that seems to only have 17GB available whilst `/home` (something I hardly ever use) is huge. Could someone explain this and if it is a problem.

Comment: mv /var/www/html /home AND THEN ln -s /home/www/html /var/www/html. It will not resize your partitions but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common out of the box setup for a server.  T

he expectation is that the most common deployment is as a file server, and so `/home` tends to get the most space.

If your intent for the server is different, then you'd resize the partitions accordingly at build time.

So no, it isn't a problem as such, though it might not be the structure you were after.